# Web development add-on for Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing web sites using HTML, and I have seen that Chrome has this great built-in tool called "Inspect Elements" which allows me to see all the HTML elements which are applied by default and their default browser properties.

I was wondering if there is similar add-on for Firefox? Please suggest a good one. BaAsically to inspect and edit HTML.

Comment: Firebug has been around a lot longer than Chrome's tool.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug. Better than Chrome's! http://getfirebug.com

Answer (score 0):

Download Firebug for FireFox.

http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is the tool of choice.